# css files for 1 site collection are being served as application/octet-stream Content-type instead of text/css

Tags: 2010, css, iis, iis7

I got 2 SP2010 (win 2008R2) farms and 2 web-applications running on them:

Farm1 (prd) -> app-prd 
Farm2 (tst) -> app-tst

(app-prd and app-tst are FQDN http links)

on those web-applications we've created one site collection (in / path) and deployed custom solution with some application, both sites are using the same version of this custom solution,

one site (app-prd) renders ok, second site (app-tst) is rendering with no css, ugly "icon map" and some unwanted texts visible to end-users; administrative pages are also without css,

after some checking i discovered that on app-tst I see errors in IE/Firefox console:

CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch

for 2 css files

the css files are served as application/octet-stream and on other collecions as text/css

i've created app-tst/site/1 site collection for testing purpose but it works just fine,

on IIS Mime-Types i see proper entry - .css -> text/css

tried iisreset and pool recycling with no luck,

i am running out of ideas :)

Comment: Which browser you are using? Try clearing browser cache.

Comment: IE / Firefox on seceral different machines with win 7/8.1, browser cache cleared

Comment: http://murmurofawebmaster.blogspot.com/2011/02/css-delivered-as-content-type.html

Comment: this link doesn't contain real solution and real problem source, only workaround (i supose)

Comment: I am experiencing a very similar problem. Did you ever figure out the root cause of your issue? Thanks!